# How to resize a Windows Vista partition to use the extra space for dual-booting with Fedora using GRUB?

Tags: windows-vista, multi-boot, fedora, fedora-11

I just got a new laptop and it came pre-installed with a Windows Vista. But I am a Fedora user.  Now, it would be easy for me to just remove Vista and use the entire disk space for Fedora. But the thing is, I thought that it would be nice to keep the Windows partition for non-Linux non-Windows-on-a-VM tasks whatever those tasks are.

Right now, the hard drive has 2 partitions: `C:\`, which is the primary partition where the current apps installed is already occupying 17GB of hard disk space, and `D:\`, the RECOVERY partition. What I want to do is to resize the hard disk space of the C drive to 30GB, keep the RECOVERY partition, then use the remaining hard disk space for Fedora 11 while having them dual-boot using GRUB.

How can I accomplish such setup without having the need to reinstall Vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the partition shrinking function of Fedora during the Fedora installation. During the installation of Fedora, I shrank the Windows Vista partition to my desired size (50GB). And then I went on with my usual installation steps.

After the restart, choosing `other` (Windows Vista) showed 'BOOTMGR is missing'. The solution was to boot to Fedora and edit grub.conf to point the second option to the Vista partition.

Answer (score 2):

you can get a [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) live CD, then boot to Gparted and do any resizing you want :)

Comment: Why use GParted when Vista has it's own disk shrink utility?

Comment: Actually I use Gparted in the Ubuntu live CD. I just don't like the partitioner that come with Vista. It looks cumbersome to me :D
Besides, it doesn't show clearly what is primary, what is extended and logical, which Gparted does. And I'm afraid that I would make some mistake on that.

Comment: I found out that Vista's disk management tool can only resize the partitions down to 50% of the original size.